# How can I set up a noreply@mydomain.com email in SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I want to be able to send messages using SES. My sender's email is noreply@mydomain.com . The domain and sender's email are verified identities in SES. Now whenever my app sends an email, I don't want the receiver to be able to reply to the email I sent. How can I configure the sender email so that it never receives an email as reply from the user?

Comment: Did you figure this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is going to sound simple but follow this guide. There is one step though I struggled with which I got lost for hours on. [Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/receiving-email.html)

Make sure when you're creating the MX record, you need to add the inbound SMTP as well as the normal email smtp.

```
10 inbound-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
11 email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

You need to add both in order to receive email as well. Then, your rule sets will work as intended.